# ExtJS - disable depending on input value

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have the code below to create a text field in the form.

```
buildForm : function() {
    this.time = new Ext.form.TextField({
        name : 'estimate',
        allowBlank : false,
        fieldLabel : 'Estimate',
        onBlur : function(field) {
            return this.setValue(this.getValue().replace('.', ','));
        }
    });
}
```

It works correctly.

Now, when I render this form, and in this field is `value="abc"`, I need to set `disabled` to this field.

I tried:

```
disabled : function() { return this.getValue() == 'abc' ? true : false;}
disabled : function(field) { return this.getValue() == 'abc' ? true : false;}
disabled : function(field) { return field.getValue() == 'abc' ? true : false;}
disabled : this.getValue() == 'abc' ? true : false
```

But nothing of this work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
change: function(field, newValue,) {
     field.setDisabled(newValue == 'abc');
}
```

Check [API](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api) for more info on events, methods for [TextField](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-event-change)

**UPD:**

If you need to disable textfield only on form render, just add this line in **buildForm** function.

```
this.time.setDisabled(this.time.getValue() == 'abc')
```

Another way is to add logic on **TextField's** **render** event.

```
render: function(field) {
    field.setDisabled(field.getValue() == 'abc')
}
```

**UPD 2:**

I suppose, that your issue is on way of setting value or in the order.

Here's a working sample.

Notice this.time.setValue('abc') 
instead of this.time.value = 'abc', which won't work.

```
buildForm: function() {



        this.timeFld = Ext.create('Ext.form.TextField', {
            name: 'estimate',
            allowBlank: false,
            fieldLabel: 'Estimate',
            onBlur: function(field) {
                return this.setValue(this.getValue().replace('.', ','));
            },
            listeners: {
                render: function(field) {
                 field.setDisabled(field.getValue() == 'abc');
                }
            }
        });

        this.timeFld.setValue('abc');

       // this.time.setDisabled(this.time.getValue() == 'abc');

        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'Test',
            items: [
             this.timeFld
            ],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });

      //  alert(this.timeFld.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: I don't need to set disabled on `change` event. When the form is rendered, the field isn't disabled (when the form is rendered first time, field was empty or had other value than `'abc'`). When the form was filled earlier, and the field value was `abc`, it has to have `disabled`.

Comment: @panther, check if update works. Thing is that binding works only in ExtJS 5. You should attach disabling to an event in ExtJS 4.

Comment: your updated code, `this.time.setDisabled(...)` returns `TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.getValue()')`.

Comment: @panther, sorry, updated to this.time.getValue(). Should work now.

Comment: It still doesn't work. `console.log(this.time.getValue());` returns `undefined`. I put that below `this.time = new ... {}` of course.

Comment: @panther where and when do you set the value? Check updated code sample.

Comment: hm, I don't knwo where data are set exactly... See the ExtJS the second day. Can I send you the whole file into mail?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fLL1sy4g/, `buildForm` begins on line 283, my field name is `timeEstimate`, lines 295-308. Function `setValues` is on lines 214-222, but is use for a calendar data only. Not sure where data from DB are taken here... :-(

Comment: @panther, sorry, but its a Q&A website, not ODesk. People help each other, but by not doing their work instead of them. Check my code provided in upd 2 and try to figure out, what's wrong in your code. If youll still have issues,ask another question.

Comment: It do nothing. No error in console, all fields are enabled.

Comment: I just wanted to show you the whole code, if there is st. what I don't see and it can helps to solve this problem.

Comment: @panther, your issue is not in disabling field depending on input, but in loading the value. Just dig into the code and find a solution. For disabling use setDisabled function. How to apply that in your huge code is out of question.

Comment: okay, this is what I actually have. https://jsfiddle.net/fto4c5m7/. `Blur event` see the field value correctly, `render listener` not. And I don't know why.

Comment: The code you posted works, but I have no `onReady` in my code. I found when the form is rendered, it seems we are closer. In code I have `this.win.render`, it should be the place when the form is rendered. When I put after that `console.log(this.timeEstimate)`, in console I see `Object: ... rendered: true, value: "2,00", ...`. I put on the next line `console.log(this.timeEstimate.getValue());` and it returns blank into console. Why? It's so strange, isn't it?